# Simple password program

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple little program that tells the user that there password is wrong.
But when I want the program to bring back the password they entered and say that it's wrong it won't let me. Somebody help me..

```
username = raw_input("Please enter your username: ")
password = raw_input("Please enter your password: ")
fail1 = raw_input("Your password is very insecure, make a new one: ")
print "Your password [password] is too weak!"
```

Comment: What do you by 'it won't let you'? Is there more code you're not showing us?

Comment: what do you mean it won't let you? Does it error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not magically format strings, you need to do that *explicitly*:

```
print "Your password {} is too weak!".format(password)
```

See [Format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more information how the `.format()` method works.

Alternatively, use any of:

```
print "Your password", password, "is too weak!"
print "Your password %s is too weak!" % password
import string
template = string.Template("Your password ${password} is too weak!")
print template.substitute(password=password)
```

Comment: for the love of grammar geeks everywhere, please make sure you change it to "**too** weak!" (with two o's) before you implement.  (I know this was how the op had it in question, @MartijnPieters)

Comment: There you go, at least in my answer, the grammar balance is restored.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a string inside another one, you need to use %. For example:

```
print "Your password [%s] is too weak" % password
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print "Your password %s is to weak!" % password
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Your password", password, "is to weak!"
```