# Registration program

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple registration program and I cant seem to make it where when a user would register, the information would be saved and so when they log in, there account would be already registered. And for some reason the `("Password: ")` won't come up.? By the way, it will be an offline registration so could I use a .txt file or something for the database?

```
username = raw_input("Create a new username: ")
password = raw_input("Create a password: ")
firstname = raw_input("What's your first name?: ")
lastname = raw_input("What's your last name?: ")
phonenumber = raw_input("Enter your phone number.: ")
print "Thank you for signing up!"
signin = raw_input("Username: ")("Password: ")
```

Comment: whats the difference between this question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509004/simple-password-program? It feels like you should spend some time with the [official python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: That question covers the password part, but not saving the users I suppose. But I agree, make sure you look around for questions that have already been asked, before posting a new one!

Comment: Sorry if I posted the "same" question 2 times. I've been looking around and all I could find is online Facebook registration stuff. And I'm trying to make an offline registration that can remember user info, sorry for the inconvenience. @Fredrik Phil

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something here, but generally speaking in order to save users you will need some sort of database. Now, database can be a scary word because of the connotations it holds but it can come in many forms. If you're building a web application you could use something like a mySQL database, however in a python application (especially if this is for class), you would likely want to use some sort of text based file (pure text, or a csv file) or you could use an array/vector if persistence isn't a requirement.

Unfortunately without a bit more context Im not sure any of can be of much help, but I would suggest you start reading up on some of the methods I mentioned above. There are all kinds of resources available online that can help you accomplish any of the methods I mentioned. Here's a decent article that might be a good starting point: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Hope this helps!